# Best Ubuntu for a 2016 Dell Inspiron 3537

Tags: 16.04, 12.04, 18.04, updates, dell

I want to know which you but it would be best for my Dell laptop. It’s preloaded with 12.04 currently its supporting 18.04 LTS bionic beaver however it 16.04 seems to be more stable can anyone offer any advice furthermore I intend to update to the newest version today to see what happens computer is free so I’m just figuring it all out

Comment: 16.04 LTS is near EOL. So you have to upgrade to 18.04 LTS. Having 8 Gb of RAM with an SSD will create better user experience.

Comment: Create a boot disk with the latest LTS (20.04) and give it a try.  You can try it before you install it.  See if everything "looks ok" when run off the USB drive.  If so, then install it.  LTS is supported for only 5 years.  So, you shouldn't even consider 12.04 or 16.04...